# How do I route a static page in sylius

Tags: symfony, routes, sylius

I am having tourble creating and routing static pages from within the Sylius CMS.

I have had this working once but now just can not get it to work at all. Creating the content for the page works fine but when I try to save a route all I get is errors.

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Parameter "id" for route "sylius_backend_static_content_update" must
>   match ".+" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in
>   SyliusWebBundle:Backend/Content/StaticContent:update.html.twig at line
>   20.

[Image of the page I am trying to save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsYdA.png)

Any help would be appreciated as there doesn't seem to be any documentation on this part of sylius.

Comment: Can you post the line 20 of  your update.html.twig file?

Comment: this is line 20 - <form action="{{ path('sylius_backend_static_content_update', {'id': static_content.id}) }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>

Answer (score 0):

May be you can have a look into the link below. I also had some problems with the routes while creating the pages. I had solved it by adding some info into the database. Hope this link helps you.

https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Standard/issues/78

Happy Syliusing ^^